# close EntityManagerFactory on ending of debugging session

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

I am new in java ee programming. 
I have web app which uses jpa for connecting to database. 
My problem is, after debugging the program, the entityManagerFactory remains open (I GUESS). So in the next debugging session I have errors such as "java.lang.ClassCastException: entity.User cannot be cast to entity.User". If I restart the web server the problem goes away. How I can resolve the issue please help.

I am using netbeans BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find a way to solve this problem. I just created a junit testcase(or an executable) that closes the jpa. Before ending the debug session I simply run the test.